# Mark label as red when required input is not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Lets say I have this form input element:

```
<label for="myInput">Label Text</label>
<input type="text" name="special" id="myInput" required>
```

Now since this input is required, and I don't enter any values in this field, I get an error saying

> This field is required.

**Validation**: It appears that the existing default html5 validation is overridden by jQuery validator. There is magic happening, and I see that I can change the existing style behavior by changing the below css

```
select.error,
input[type=text].error,
input[type=email].error,
input[type=password].error {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
label.error {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

I also notice that in the error situation the above html becomes like below:

```
<label for="myInput">Label Text</label>
<input type="text" name="special" id="myInput" required>
<label class="error" for="myInput">This field is required.</label>
```

- How do you think validation is happening in the first place?
- How do I make the text in the first label element text as red?
- In the code, where should I be looking to answer the above questions?

Comment: first use id attribute for label, then document.getElementById('labelid').style.color = "red"; , you can write this code on some button click or onblur of text box

Comment: Update your validate.js and add a specific class to label too where it adds a class in input for errors.

Comment: How you are validating the required field? `onblur`? `onclick`???

Comment: script for validation ?

Comment: Improved formatting for readability

Answer (score 0):

first use id attribute for label

```
<label for="myInput" id="mylabel">Label Text</label>
```

, then `document.getElementById('mylabel').style.color = "red";`

> you can write this code on some button click or onblur of text box

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1ng67aLe/)

If you are using jquery then you can refer the below code

```
$( "#myInput" ).blur(function() {
 document.getElementById('mylabel').style.color = "red";
});
```

**JS solution**

html

```
<label for="myInput" id="mylabel">Label Text</label>
<input type="text" name="special" onblur="blurFunction()" onfocus="focusFunction()"  id="myInput">
```

js

```
function blurFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('mylabel').style.color = "red";

}
```